# setting contentType for Json request in HttpsRequest using Scala

Tags: scala, akka-http

trying to send httpRequest to remote server but the server seems to be not getting it, curl command like this works fine:

```bash
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d @payload.json -u "user:password" url
```

but if we try from a scala program, endpoint does not seem to receive the request. most likely server look for ContentType.application/json in the header!
sample code:

```scala
val body = "[{\"Field1\":\"XYZ\",\"Field2\":1,\"ID:\"test\"}]"
 
authorization = Some(headers.Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(username, password)))
val request = HttpRequest(
method = HttpMethods.POST,
uri = url,
headers = authorization.toList,
entity = HttpEntity(
ContentTypes.`application/json`,
s"source=$body&language=Scala&theme==Sunburst"
)
)

val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(request)
responseFuture
.onComplete {
case Success(res) => println(res.toString())
case Failure(_) => sys.error("something wrong" + responseFuture.toString)
}
```

this returns http code = 200, OK which is fine, but not getting the response as we get it via curl command!

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that you're not sending JSON from the Scala code. Maybe that's the explanation? What's the content of `payload.json` in the curl command?

Comment: Also could you clarify which library you are using here for the http client?

Comment: payload.json is the json string like 'body' in the above program. Does not HttpEntity with content type and body, inside the request, sends json request with correct headers? I am using import akka.http.scaladsl.Http

Answer (score 0):

Hard to definitely answer as the server you're calling doesn't seem to give a helpful error message or HTTP code.

You're sending a body which is not JSON claiming it is.

Change your `entity` to:

```scala
entity = HttpEntity(
  ContentTypes.`application/json`,
  body
)
```

Not sure, what are `source=..&language=...` supposed to be? If these are query parameters, add them in the `uri` (optionally use the [`Uri`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.5.2/akka/http/scaladsl/model/Uri.html) class to better describe things).

---

Note that you could write your `body` more easily with the `"""` syntax:

```scala
val body = """
[
  {"Field1":"XYZ","Field2":1,"ID:"test"}
]
"""
```

Comment: appreciate you feedback. made changes, but the output does not change..checking with remote side if they are seeing the request correctly and responding to it. sorry i am new to scala/https

Comment: In case you have a sample program which sends json request (with user/password in the header), please share. appreciate any help.

Comment: Far entity claims that they did not receive the body text! .. which seems to be the issue.

Comment: I recommend you to setup unit tests (with a mock server for instance) that assert on the data sent then. You should be able to debug this locally without having to discuss with the real server team.